# Article web Scraping using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to get the article text,header and published date of the article from the below URL

https://www.argusmedia.com/en/news/2214037-us-hrc-prices-rise-as-supply-remains-tight

while I am trying to scrape the 'article' container with class "news-container cf" it returns 0 rows.

#Reprex Code

````
url = "https://www.argusmedia.com/en/news/2214037-us-hrc-prices-rise-as-supply-remains-tight"

# Request
r1 = requests.get(url, verify=False)
r1.status_code

print(r1.status_code)
# We'll save in coverpage the cover page content
coverpage = r1.content

# Soup creation
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, "html5lib")

# News identification
coverpage_news = soup1.find_all('article' , class_ ='news-container cf')
len(coverpage_news) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because this is being loaded dynamically, you need to call the APIs directly

```py
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.argusmedia.com/api/news/2214037/us-hrc-prices-rise-as-supply-remains-tight').json()

body = data['AmpBody']
title = data['Title']
date = data['PublishedDate']
year = data['PublishedYear']

print(body, title, date, year, sep='\n')

# <article><p class="lead">US hot-roll...
# US HRC: Prices rise as supply remains tight
# 11 May
# 2021
```

Comment: The same approach is not working for these URLs:
https://www.argusmedia.com/en/news/2216495-am-informs-buyers-of-another-hrc-increase?backToResults=true&selectedMarket=Metals


https://www.argusmedia.com/en/news/2252797-libyas-es-sider-and-ras-lanuf-ports-resume-operations

Answer (score 0):

That page runs javascripts.
`Requests` is an http library and it cannot run javascript.
In order to 'see' the HTML of a javscript web page you need to process all the code on the page and actually render the content.
A way to do that is using `requests_html` module.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession  

session = HTMLSession()
resp = session.get('your_url')
# this command executes the javascripts 
resp.html.render()
```

Output:

```
resp.text

{"AmpBody":"<article><p class=\\"lead\\">US hot-rolled coil (HRC) prices continued to trend upward as supplies remain tight and demand stays elevated...}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

If you want to search for tags that match two or more CSS classes, you should use a CSS selector:

```
soup1.select("article.news-container.cf")
```